# Ear cliping - right perspective

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, perspective

I am using OpenGL. Right now I am programming 3D model loader by using ear cliping algorithm.
My main problem is which axis should I use. I have 3 options: (X Y) , (Z Y) , (X Z).
For instance, If I Have a quad - 4 points - (1, 1, 0) (-1, 1, 0) (-1, -1, 0) (1, -1, 0) I need the (X Y) axis because All the Z are the same.

So I have been trying to program some code which can know what 2 axis I need. It checks if one of the axis is the same to the others.

But this code works only when one axis is the same. When the polygon on slant the code does not work. So I have been added to the code a function check which checking if all the vertices on same line, Then I got this polygon and my code failed:

[image: ...]

You can see that at the top this is vertex, At the right one vertex and at the bottom there are 3 vertices. As you can see (X Z) is the right axis which I should fine.
If you look on the (Z Y) axis you can see this:

[image: ...]

one vertex on the left, one at the middle and 3 vertices on the right. Not all the vertices are on the same line and I can not check which axis should I use. Because if I will use the (Z Y) axis the ear cliping algorithm will not work.

How can I know which 2 axis should I use? I am using C++.

Comment: Why doesn't your ear clipping not work in the last case? Shouldn't it? You just need to use a plane where the face does not degenerate to a line.

Comment: What are you trying exactly? a binary space partition?  It seem like you want to find a plane that meet 2 axis and contain the triangle (which is impossible in most cases). If you explain a bit more the purpose of your algorithm, we may see what is wrong.

Comment: Adrian Maire - I am trying to change polygons which has more than 3 vertices to some triangles by using ear cliping algorithm. The problem is that ear cliping use 2 axis, so I need to check which 2 axis should I give it. The options are: (X Y) , (Z Y) , (X Z)

Comment: Are your quads really nonplanar? In the typical case, they are not, and you could use the plane of the quad itself insted of some axis-aligned plane.